# How can I search a Google Cloud Bucket?

Tags: search, bucket, google-cloud-platform

The "objects list" function (seen here: https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/list ) is entirely inadequate for searching on Google Cloud (ironically, since it is Google)

Perhaps I am missing how to really so search properly? Do I have to start doing my own indexing?

UPDATE:

A friend mentioned the watchAll() call for capturing changes and then presumably indexing them. But the main question remains: is there a better way to search buckets?

Answer (score 3):

I am pretty sure that the search functionality is not available on Cloud Storage. And it does not make sense either (a service like that would slow up a lot Cloud Storage).
You need to see the Cloud Storage service as an unlimited hard drive that is unlikely to fail.

When you think about it, you cannot search for a file or its content on your computer drive without walking all your files (by using a tools like the `find` command). Modern OS provide search functionalities but all they do is indexing your hard drive files on the fly when a modification comes up.

If you really want indexing your Cloud Storage content, you need to make it yourself (by using the watch functionality and AppEngine search index for instance).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I'm holding out hope that somebody has figured out a way...